# How to get perfect spaces on both sides

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

I got the following design of the logo made with the pen tool. I want to make the highlighted space perfect between each so it is symmetrical. How can I achieve that?[image: symmetrical]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you start off with a form like below you have several options to straighten up the margins:.

[image]

You can you alt drag the form, change to white and if needed bring some elements to the front/back.

[image]

Or you can add a stroke to the bottom shape. In the 'stroke panel' select "more options" in the top right and then choose "align stroke to outside"

[image]

Or click bottom element and select "Object / Path / Offset Path" and colour the new form white.

[image]

##### Clean up

Once you have on of those forms you probably want to clean it up, so you have no white in the logo and a nice transparent background. Either manually using the form as guide
[image]

Or with the Pathfinder; selecting elements to cut and clicking divide. This splits up overlapping elements allowing you to delete the not needed parts.
[image]

Comment: It may be better to teach new users to use shapebuilder over pathfinder in these kinds of cases.

Comment: Probably true as Pathfinder isn't very intuitive for beginners, though I personally never really used the shapebuilder tool.

Answer (score 11):

Simply, you dont use pentool. What you do is you use the offset command, effect or expanded stroke to give you a curve that is offset uniformly. In this case you ofset the lower shape. Then you use this curve in conjunction with shapebuilder, pathfinder, scissors to build the curve you need.

Comment: Sorry but I don’t follow. What u said. Can u expand on what you said?

Comment: Added an answer with the same solution (and some options) with screenshots – hope this makes it clear...